# Новое окно при нажатии кнопки

Tags: java, javafx

Имеется следующий код:

**main.java:**

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        String fxmlFile = "mainForm.fxml";
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent root = (Parent) loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fxmlFile));
        stage.setTitle("Экз");
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Класс `mainFromControl` (код кнопки, при нажатии на которую открывается второе окно):

```
@FXML
public void openEntry(){
    openWindow("Просмотр товара", "chartFrame");
}

private void openWindow(String title, String path) {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    Parent root = null;
    try {
        root = (Parent) loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle(title);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.show();
}
```

Контроллер второго окна

```
public class ChartFrameController {

    @FXML
    public Button firstBtn;

    public void initialize() {}
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку, выдается ошибка:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=51139:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Timofey\IdeaProjects\one\target\classes" Main
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: inputStream is null.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2455)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at Controller.mainFormControl.openWindow(mainFormControl.java:132)
    at Controller.mainFormControl.openEntry(mainFormControl.java:125)
    ... 62 more
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@FXML
public void chartBtn(MouseEvent mouseEvent) throws IOException {
    Parent chartPageParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/jfx/chartFrame.fxml"));
    Scene chartPageScene = new Scene(chartPageParent);
    Stage appStage = (Stage) ((Node)mouseEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    appStage.hide();
    appStage.setTitle("Chart");
    appStage.setScene(chartPageScene);
    appStage.show();
}
```

Comment: А как что-бы не прятать? Просто открыть окно с редактированием одной записи таблицы?

Answer (score 0):

В контроллере с кнопкой, которая должна открывать новое окно, создайте на нее ивент.

```
@FXML
void go_reg(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("error_fx.fxml"));
        Parent root1 = fxmlLoader.load();
        Stage stage1 = new Stage();
        stage1.setScene(new Scene(root1, 300, 150));
        stage1.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```